# SQL query for incoming and outgoing stocks, first and last

Tags: sql, vertica

I need to make a query that shows sales and stocks (incoming and outgoing) for each model in October 2021.
The point is that for obtaining incoming and outgoing stocks I need to get vt_stocks_cube_sz.qty respectively for the first day of month and for the last day of month .

Now I wrote just sum of stocks (SUM(vt_stocks_cube_sz.qty) as stocks) but it isn't correct.

Could you help me to split the stocks according to the rule above, I cannot understant how to write the query correctly.

```
%%time
SELECT vt_sales_cube_sz.modc_barc2 model,
        SUM(vt_sales_cube_sz.qnt) sales,
        SUM(vt_stocks_cube_sz.qty) as stocks
FROM vt_sales_cube_sz
LEFT JOIN vt_date_cube2 
    ON vt_sales_cube_sz.id_calendar_int = vt_date_cube2.id_calendar_int
LEFT JOIN vt_stocks_cube_sz ON 
    vt_stocks_cube_sz.parent_modc_barc = vt_sales_cube_sz.modc_barc AND
    vt_stocks_cube_sz.id_stock = vt_sales_cube_sz.id_stock AND 
    vt_stocks_cube_sz.id_calendar_int = vt_sales_cube_sz.id_calendar_int AND
    vt_stocks_cube_sz.vipusk_type = vt_sales_cube_sz.price_type
WHERE vt_date_cube2.wk_year_id = 2021 
        AND vt_date_cube2.wk_MoY_id = 10 
        AND vt_sales_cube_sz.id_stock IN 
            (SELECT id_stock 
            FROM vt_warehouse_cube 
            WHERE channel = \'OffLine\') 
GROUP BY vt_sales_cube_sz.modc_barc2
```

Comment: Could you not paste a few exemplary rows into your question that would correspond to the query you wrote, all joins included, but without  the `SUM()` expressions and without the `GROUP BY ` clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a robust and generalizable approach I'd suggest using [analytic functions](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/AnalyticFunctions.htm) such as FIRST_VALUE, LAST_VALUE or something slightly different with RANK or ROW_NUMBER.
A simple example follows, so you can rerun it on your side and adjust it to the specific tables/fields you're using.
N.B.: You might need some tiebreakers in case you had multiple entries for the same first/last day.

```
 with dummy_table as (
    SELECT 1 as month, 1 as day, 10 as value UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 as month, 2 as day, 20 as value UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 as month, 3 as day, 30 as value UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 as month, 1 as day, 5 as value UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 as month, 3 as day, 15 as value UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 as month, 5 as day, 25 as value 
)
SELECT 
    month, 
    day,
    case when day = first_day then 'first' else 'last' end as type,
    value,
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , FIRST_VALUE(day) over (partition by month order by day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as first_day
        , LAST_VALUE(day) over (partition by month order by day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as last_day
    FROM dummy_table 
) tmp
WHERE day = first_day OR day=last_day
```

Dummy table:

| Row | month | day | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 15 |
| 6 | 2 | 5 | 25 |

Result:

| Row | month | day | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | first | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | last | 30 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | first | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 | last | 25 |